# Updating to windows 8.1 enterprise edition

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have a windows 8 enterprise edition. I want to update it to windows 8.1. As the standard procedure says to open store and in store choose windows update but I am not finding any the windows update tile. Is there any patch to apply before I check for update?

Please tell me how to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj203353.aspx):

> Volume license versions of Windows 8, Windows 8 Enterprise, and
>   Windows 8 Enterprise Eval versions cannot be upgraded from the Windows
>   Store. You must use media to upgrade these editions.

You should use an ISO that comes through your volume license channel.

Comment: Where is the download link available? I think microsoft website doesn't have the link to download windows 8.1